# How to call a JavaScript function, declared in <body>, in the body when I want to call it

Tags: javascript, html

I've code like below

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetRandomNumber() {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            return x;
        }
    </script>

    // GetRandomNumber() is not calling
    <script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=' +  GetRandomNumber(); + '" \></script>
</body>
```

How can i resolve it ?

Comment: You will need `document.write` or creating a script tag with `document.createElement('script')`

Comment: The thing that baffles me here is how do you think the browser would know that this bizarre "filename" is actually code...?

Comment: That's not how JavaScript is executed.

Comment: Try to remove the semicolon

Comment: @CaioFontes Seriously?

Comment: To be clear, the `src` of a `script` element is used exclusively for locating the JavaScript resource file. It can be in the local filesystem, or with a fully-qualified URL, can be at a remote location. No code execution will take place directly within the `src`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `document.write` which will be render blocking:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.write('<script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=' +  GetRandomNumber() + '"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

Or create the script tag by hand (Usually recommended method):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.type = 'text/javascript';
   s.src = 'app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=' + GetRandomNumber();
   document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: In Page View source,  random value is not generating. it is showing same like below (Above approach 1)
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.write('<script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=' + GetRandomNumber() + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Yes, you will need to inspect element to see how the DOM is, view source will only show you how it was served from the server and `document.write` will dynamically change the DOM.

Comment: I'm expecting <script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=some int"></script> on View source.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Then don't use JavaScript, but use a server side language instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just call JavaScript functions in that manner. You need to call them from within a `script` tag, or from a separate file included using a `script` tag.

Instead, in your existing script, use `document.write()` to add your new markup including the randomly generated number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function GetRandomNumber() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    return x;
  }

  document.write('<script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js?dev=' + GetRandomNumber() + '"></script>');

</script>
```

Also, you were writing your script tag as `<script ... /></script>` when it should be `<script ...></script>`